# Git merge different file names

Tags: git, merge

Here's my scenario:

I'm working on fixing bugs in `file1` in a local branch. My coworker is in his own local branch, merging `file1` into `file2` in a refactor. He finishes his work and merges back into master and pushes. Now `file1` no longer exists in the HEAD.

When I do a pull and try to merge my `file1` changes back into master, what will happen? Is git smart enough to account for this or will I have to merge my changes manually?

Comment: Create a local branch to do the merge so you can find out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you don't merge *files*, you merge *revisions* (or rather lines of development).

Second, git uses similarity based heuristic to **detect renames**, so if `file2` is similar enough to `file1`, then git should automatically merge your and his changes into `file2`.  If not, you would get 'CONFLICT(modify/delete)' (I think) you would have to resolve manually.

Comment: I played around and cooked up a script which makes life easier in 'CONFLICT(delete/modify)' cases. Should also work for 'CONFLICT(modify/delete)'. Have a look: https://gist.github.com/894374

Answer (score 2):

It depends.... was there a `git mv file1 file2` did git recognize this as a rename? if it did then it might recognize this... otherwise it will probably just try to create a new file1. you may have to do some manual merge intervention or a post merge patch. Also this is git TIAS worst case scenario you roll back the merge before pushing.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether there was a `git mv`. Either git recognizes it as a rename or it doesn't.